# (Java) Methods, having issues with displaying even numbers properly

Tags: java

Let me start off by saying that I'm fairly new to programming and as such, I've been using references in hopes to better learn Java programming, as trial and error is how I learn best. However, I'm currently stumped and have no idea what to do.

I am trying to get a user to input 5 numbers into an array, and then have the program display the numbers back to the user, including how many are "even" and what numbers they are. For example, if a user were to enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The program would ideally output "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" of which two are even, the even numbers are "2" and "4"

As is, the code executes well, but the resulting "numbers which are even" always results in 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

I would greatly appreciate if anyone was able to provide some assistance or tips on how to improve, thank you.

```
package PracticeExam1;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numArray = loadArray(scan);
        double largeCount = countLarge(numArray);
        int i, evenCount = 0;
        int [] arr = new int[5];
        
        System.out.println("The array contains: " + Arrays.toString(numArray));
        System.out.println(largeCount + " of these values are even numbers.");
        evenCount = CountEven(arr, 5);
    }
    
    public static int[] loadArray(Scanner sc)
    {
        // Integer array of size 5
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number to store in the array: ");
            arr[i] = (int) scnr.nextDouble();
        }
        
        return arr;
    }
    
    public static int countLarge(int[] a)
    {
        int lc = 0;
        for(int e : a)
        {
            if(e % 2 == 0) {
                lc++;
            }
        } 
        
        return lc;
    }
    
    public static int CountEven(int [] arr, int even)
    {
        int evenPos, 
                evenArr = 0;
        System.out.print("\n List of Even Numbers in this Array are: ");  
        for(evenPos = 0; evenPos < arr.length; evenPos++)
        {
            if(arr[evenPos] % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[evenPos] +" ");
                evenArr++;
            }
        }
        return evenArr;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you try `nextInt()` instead of `nextDouble()`?

Comment: you send `arr` to `CountEven`. `arr` is not initialized. you probably meant to send `numArray`

Comment: Your `evenCount` results from processing the `arr` array,  but it  contains zeros only - your actual data are in `numArray`....

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Comment: That was the issue CiaPan, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you have never added any number to your evenArr, so it can only print 0,0,0,0,0.
I've made a example how you can do this:

```
 public static int CountEven(int [] arr, int even)
    {
        int[] evenArr = new int[even];
        int evenCnt = 0;
        System.out.print("\n List of Even Numbers in this Array are: ");  
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i] +" ");
                evenArr[evenCnt] = arr[i];
                evenCnt ++;
            }
        }
        return evenArr;
    }
```

Regards
Beni